# region field remains empty in Magento2 customer registration

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account, register

I am having problems with register.phtml template. When dropdownbox appears for **region_id**, select one of them and then save the customer, it throws an exception telling that region is a required filed.

I guess that it is because the hidden input box, whose id is "region" remains empty.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a field that I have added to customer address in database, which was required. I have removed that field, and problem solved.